# Spring Boot - String to Enum conversion accepts value and index of the enum. How to reject numeric inputs and only accept enum value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

I have some simple enums like below.

```
public enum Status {
  ACTIVE,
  PASSIVE;

  private Status() {
  }
}
```

I have a String status field in my REST service input object.

It converts it to PASSIVE when the service receives both requests.

**CASE 1**
**status = 1**

```
{
    "name": "Walter",
    "surname": "White"
    "status": "1"
}
```

**CASE 2**
**status = "PASSIVE"**

```
{
    "name": "Walter",
    "surname": "White"
    "status": "PASSIVE"
}
```

I do not want the default convertor accepts the numeric inputs (CASE 1). I mean I do not want it to convert 1 to PASSIVE by using the index of the enum.

I want it only accepts Non numeric values as it is in CASE 2.

Also consider that I have many enums like this and I want to apply the restriction to all my enums.

How can I make it works as I explained above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

By default, Number for Enum deserialize by mapping enum ordinal. Add configuration [DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS) as true in ObjectMapper which is by default false.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS, true);
    return objectMapper;
  }
}
```

---

Another way is to write a custom annotation for enum validation. And use it on the field with possible values

```
@EnumNamePattern
private Status status;
```

Custom Annotation for enum validation

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnumNamePatternValidator.class)
public @interface EnumNamePattern {
    String message() default "invalid";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And write validator for the annotation

```
public class EnumNamePatternValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EnumNamePattern, Enum<?>> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Enum<?> value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) return true;
        return Arrays.stream(Status.values()).anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(value.name()));
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use this solution I will have to update regexp of all the parameters  that reference the enum when a new value is added to the Enum. Is there a generic way to reject numeric values for all enums.

That is why I did not wanted to apply this. Because it is not maintainable. I better apply a easier solution. Thank you for your answer. I am glad but I am still looking for a different solution.

Comment: By the way I want to reject value during Strin to Enum convertion. I do not need to filter the enum values. I want to stop what converts 1 to PASSIVE in my example.

Comment: @cavo I think reset config is the easiest solution.

Comment: JacksonConfig was what I ve been looking for. I also used global exception handler to return the root cause of the exception.

Thanks a lot.